# B2C Sign Up and Sign In Policy - Self-Service Reset Password redirects back to change password

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-ad-b2c, aad-b2c

In my Azure B2C Sign Up and Sign In Policy I have "Self-service password reset" ticked.

I don't have any reset password policy, as I understand this isn't necessary.

The password reset works, however after the user resets their password, they're redirected back to here in my .NET Core 5.0 application (I know this because I set a breakpoint to check):

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SignIn()
        {
            return Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
```

... then the user is sent back to the Azure B2C Password Reset page again, where they enter their email address and request a verify code (again).

Any ideas on why this happens and why the user doesn't go back to my home page after resetting their password?

Once they're redirected back for the 2nd time, then can click cancel, and then they're back in my application, already signed in after the first password reset.

Here is what the browser is doing:

[image: 1) User enters passsword]

[image: 2) Browser then does this]

[image: 3) User sent back here]

[[image: 4) Going through password reset again, the second time it lands on home page4]

Comment: I believe this is a bug, the issue is related to a claim that is set in the cookie after doing the forgot password flow, and once set, if a user visits the sign in/up policy again, they are sent to the forgot password step. For now, you should first investigate why your app is even sending the user to sign in again after doing forgot password.

Comment: Thanks Jas, do you have any clues as to how I can investigate why my app is sending the user to sign in again after doing password reset?

Comment: Any logic on the controller other than the [authorize] attribute that triggers a sign in? Any custom Authorize filter being used? Are the claims different between sign in and password reset?

Comment: Could you please share the correlation id? What is the error code? If you are getting error code such as AADSTS50126? Please refer  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/38035/aadsts50126-invalid-grant-error-validating-credent.html for more information.